# why I am not able to use video trimmer and video compressor together

Tags: android, video

I am using **K4l video trimmer** and **sillicompressor** ..but I am getting lot of errors ...I cant find way to solve the problem can any one know how to solve this ...some now said that it is because k4l video trimmer uses mp4parser from GitHub...and sillicompressor uses a isoparser in lib folder which is a jar

**error**

```
 More than one file was found with OS independent path 'builddef.lst'
```

Comment: I am facing same problem here..